# All files named __init__ on my vim's buffers

Tags: python, vim, buffer

The `__init__` files of Python modules are not really explicit. On my buffer's list I have things like this:

```
b/f/__init__ > b/k/__init__ > b/__init__ > b/f/foo
```

How is it possible to name my buffers differently?

Comment: You should ask on the issue tracker of the plugin you use to display that buffer list.

Comment: Indeed, I could do this!